# Почему keyboard работает через раз?

Tags: python, клавиатура, распознавание-речи

Я написал этот код для распознавания речи и написания его на клавиатуре

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyautogui as pag
import time
import pyttsx3
import keyboard as kb
 

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', 'voices[0].id')

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def recognition():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speak("говорите")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU"))
        return r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            kb.write(recognition())
            pag.press('enter')
            time.sleep(5)

            if(recognition().lower() == 'завершение'):
                break
        except:
            speak("Вы промолчали")
            time.sleep(1)
            pass
```

Я смотрел на то, что распознает программа, и она распознает мою речь каждый раз, но при этом пишется она через раз, я переписывал код, но не понимаю из-за чего эта проблема

Вот фото работы кода и его вывод [image: То, что выводит keyboard.write()]

[image: И то, что распознает код]

Answer (score 0):

Я покопался в самой либе, и данная ошибка из-за моей системы(macOS), если у кого-либо будет подобная проблема, то попробуйте использовать другие модули, например, puautogui или pynput

Comment: «Мне кажется» это не очень подходит для ответа на ваш же вопрос.